# Switching between merged windows (tabs) of the same application

Tags: shortcut, window-manager

The shortcut for switching between windows of the same application <kbd>Command-~</kbd> doesn't seem to work when attempting to switch between merged application windows (when the windows are listed in tabs). Anyone know how to fix this or of another shortcut that might do the trick?

Note that I'm not trying to switch between the tabs inside an application window (using <kbd>Control-Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Control-Shift-Tab</kbd>), but between instances of the application merged into a single window.

It seems that there are also 2 variations of window merging behavior:

1. Merges the windows of an application into tabs inside the application (as can be seen in the Terminal and Text applications).
2. Merges the windows of an application as tabs each containing a separate instance of the application (which can contain it's own tabs).

[image: Example of merged application windows for the Atom application]

Comment: What do you mean with "merged application windows"? Can you provide an example and/or screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot shows a Terminal window with two tabs? Still confused what you mean with merged

Comment: If there is a Terminal application with four tabs running inside the Terminal window, and you want to switch between these four tabs, the required shortcut is application specific